# relation between tangent plane and rectifying plane

Tags: geometry

Tangent plane is perpendicular to normal. 
Rectifying plane is plane containing tangent and binormal and is perpendicular to normal. 
I want to know if both are same. 
I have not read anywhere the name used interchangeably. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please state what _binormal_ means?

Comment: @Qwerty the normal which is perpendicular to osculating plane at a point is called binormal. Obviously, binormal is perpendicular to principal normal.

Comment: Please have the habit of accepting answers. And if you don't please leave a comment why so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If binormal is perpendicular to the principle normal, then it **must** lie in the Tangent plane. By that definition, your **Rectifying plane** and **Tangent plane** are necessarily synonyms..